# Using Variables within Laravel Blade Directives

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This is a question concerning using variables within a Laravel blade directive. I have a site with a variety of dashboards. Each dashboard has a landing page that shows cards for each subpage.

I have a landing page blade template, that contains this bit of code:

```
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-lg-3">

        <div class="col">
          @yield('card-1')
                </div>

        <div class="col">
          @yield('card-2')
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          @yield('card-3')
        </div>
  </div>
```

The idea is that the child blade can include each card with it's own details, like so:

@section('card-2')




This is my card



@stop

This works just fine, but I want to scale this up. On some pages, I don't want to use every card slot. In fact, I don't want to really fiddle with the page at all. I want the cards to be dynamically generated. I created a database table to hold all of the card info, including whether or not a card should be visible.

On the pages I will then just call the pages model and select only the visible card, and then loop through the collection to create the card. After testing, every bit works except for dynamically setting the section name using a counter variable.

For example, here's some content in a landing page blade:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Page;
$rootPath = url('/');

//Get only pages that are visible for this dashboard
$pages = Page::where('dashboard_id', 2)->where('menu_display', 1)->get();

//increment counter, for dynamic card section naming
$i=1;
?>

//Loop through each page result
<?php foreach($pages as $page) {  ?>
@section('card-{{$i}}') //Set card section dynamically; THIS FAILS

    <div id="{{$page->page_name}}" class="" title=""></div>
    <div class="card" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="{{$page->page_tooltip}}">
        <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/{{$page->page_url_slug}}">
            <img src="{{URL::to('/')}}/assets/img/{{$page->page_img}}"
                 class="card-img-top dashboard-thumbnail mx-auto d-block" alt="{{$page->page_title}}">
            <div class="card-body mb-3">
                <h4 class="card-text">{{$page->page_title}}</h4>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
@stop
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The failure point is trying to dynamically designate section name directive, so `@section('card-{{$i}}')` fails, whereas if I hardcode `@section('card-2')`, the card renders, but of course only one renders because card-2 section content just gets overwritten.

What is a workaround to this?

Comment: You might want to consider using [components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components) and [slots](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#slots).

Comment: should be `@section("card-$i")` or `@section('card-'.$i)`. You cannot use blade within a blade directive, and you don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this approach. It's not the most elegant solution, but it gets the jon done and is a good stopgap until I can find a better solution (possibly using components or slots, as suggested by  user @Peppermintology).

```
<?php foreach($pages as $page) {  ?>

<?php if($i == 1) { ?> @section('card-1') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 2) { ?> @section('card-2') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 3) { ?> @section('card-3') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 4) { ?> @section('card-4') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 5) { ?> @section('card-5') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 6) { ?> @section('card-6') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 7) { ?> @section('card-7') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 8) { ?> @section('card-8') <?php } ?>
<?php if($i == 9) { ?> @section('card-9') <?php } ?>
    <div id="{{$page->page_name}}" class="" title=""></div>
    <div class="card" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="{{$page->page_tooltip}}">
        <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/{{$page->page_url_slug}}">
            <img src="{{URL::to('/')}}/assets/img/{{$page->page_img}}"
                 class="card-img-top dashboard-thumbnail mx-auto d-block" alt="{{$page->page_title}}">
            <div class="card-body mb-3">
                <h4 class="card-text">{{$page->page_title}}</h4>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
@stop
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I am checking the incrementor count, and then showing the section name that correlates to it. I am going up to nine, since that's the maximum number of pages per dashboard.